# libcurl issue after upgrading from Debian 10 to 11 cannot compile c++ program

Tags: debian, curl, upgrade, gcc

I have a program that's compiles just fine in Debian 10. It uses libcurl-dev.

Tried to migrate it on Debian 12, and I got errors like:

```
undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
```

and so on...

So I decide to test a Debian 10 to Debian 11 upgrade.
And I got the exact same errors.

What's changed on 11 and 12 and I cannot compile a c++ program anymore ?
`Makefile` never changed. Same exact code from `git pull`.
.h files the same, `#include <curl/curl.h>`.

Basically nothing changed in code, I just pull it from git.
In 10 it works, in 11 doesn't, in 12 neither.
Upgrading from 10 that worked to 11, doesn't work either.

Comment: is this a program you wrote? You mention `git pull` so there's a strong chance in my mind that it's someone elses program

Comment: I work with a local gitlab setup

Comment: that answers a question nobody asked